# Python Module Installation Problems

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a ton of trouble installing modules. At first I thought I had messed with my python installation on mac os x but I installed a virtual machine and ubuntu 11.04 and have similar troubles. Why are both os x and ubuntu failing with the same error?

For example I can't install tkinter with it failing:

```
Installing collected packages: tkinter-pypy
  Running setup.py install for tkinter-pypy
    building '_tkinter' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DWITH_APPINIT -I/usr/include/tcl -I/usr/include/tk -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_tkinter.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/_tkinter.o
    src/_tkinter.c:74:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/pfm/build/tkinter-pypy/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-sMB5Wi-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

building '_tkinter' extension

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DWITH_APPINIT -I/usr/include/tcl -I/usr/include/tk -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_tkinter.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/_tkinter.o

src/_tkinter.c:74:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/pfm/build/tkinter-pypy/setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-sMB5Wi-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /home/pfm/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: I thought Tkinter was a built-in package. Have you tried importing it already?

Comment: I'm putting my comment as an answer, I checked a couple installs and it was available without any action by me.

Comment: Missing dependencies(in /usr/lib/ or somewhere of the like). That what I could extract from error log. And TKinter is in Pythin stdlib, so you shouldn't have to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the error, but Tkinter should be available with your Python install. Have you tried to `import Tkinter`. On a related note I'd definitely recommend using setuptools (aka. [easy_install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)) or one of the other similar installation tools.

**EDIT**

If Tkinter is still not available, then, on Linux, try `locate lib-tk` and adding it to your python path

`import sys;
    sys.path.append(PATH_TO_TK)`

Then check out the Wiki to get the setup to stick: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

**Another EDIT**

A simple work around might be to install IDLE, which depends on Tkinter (noted by the OP).

Comment: No luck for me with the package that came with ubuntu.

Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter

Comment: @PFM case matters try `import Tkinter`

Comment: >>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package

Comment: I guess it's not there, odd. I'd `easy_install python-tk` then.

Comment: Actually that's not working, but I see Tkinter in my package manager on Debian.

Comment: I fixed my problem. On Ubuntu you have to install IDLE as a separate package. Once going to my package manager I realized IDLE was unchecked, thanks Josh.

Comment: @PFM surely, I'll add that to the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I encountered exactly the same problem when trying to install tkinter-pypy on Ubuntu 11.04. The error message shows that it's looking for tcl.h file in /usr/include/tcl, but it's not there. I have to install the dev version of the tcl library (I installed tcl8.4-dev).

`sudo apt-get install tcl8.4-dev`

This installs the header files to /usr/include/tcl8.4. I then created a symlink /usr/include/tcl pointing to that. I also installed the dev version of the tk library (e.g. tk8.4-dev) which installed the tk.h header (needed too by tkinter-pypy) in the /usr/include/tcl directory.

After these steps, tkinter-pypy can be installed successfully.

Comment: Thanks for info, let's see if I will be able to figure out how to do it in Windows (maybe edit library location in setup.py to location of tcl source I downloaded as conclusion of same struggle. I think however that your tcl (8.4) is little out of date. The source I downloaded in tcl8.5.