# Install Tkinter without root access

Tags: python, configuration, installation, tkinter, tcl

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to install Tkinter on a Linux system without having root privileges. According to the second answer to this question: [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python) there is a way, and it involves downloading the source of Tkinter and TCL and then running their install routines in custon directories created one level below the home directory. I did that and everything except for the last step where it says run setup.py build and setup.py install. I can't find these files anywhere, an can't build them either. Does anyone know what the lasts tep of this routine is, and could possibly expound upon it? Thanks.

For reference: the sequence of instructions for installing the sources once you have the tar files is the follwing:

```
cd ~/tcl8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/<user> --exec-prefix=/home/<user>
make
make install

cd ~/tk8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/<user> --exec-prefix=/home/<user> --with-tcl=/home/<user>/tcl8.5.11/unix
make
make install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't have sufficient reputation points to comment, but isn't this question [Install Tkinter in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644371/python-module-installation-problems) similar to yours??.

To summarize, if you are sure that `Tkinter` is not already installed (and not that your python path is not correctly configured), I would suggest you to use some tools like `easy_install` and then do

```
easy_install --prefix=<local-dir-in-python-path> python-tk
```

generally I use `~/.local/` as the prefix.

`easy_install` can be installed by installing `setuptools`

Comment: I tried something similar to that, but it keeps telling me that the library python-tk isn't in the package list. The only things it does have are several tkinter upgrades that need tkinter installed already in order to run. And nothing in regards to tcl.

Comment: hmm I see... well maybe you can use ``easy_install`` on the source you downloaded (that way it won't tell you that it cannot find ``python-tk`` and will do the necessary cycle of make/build)

Comment: Okay, I was confused as to what source I downloaded for each, but I'll give it a try with some experimentation.